# Error when trying to display my array?

Tags: php, arrays

So I am trying to display an array from a database that I have. When I run the script the script, I get an internal server error. Now I am not sure if this has to do with my config script or if I am not cycling through my array properly.

```
include 'config.php';

$conn = name2;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Feild FROM Season 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Feild " . $row["Feild"]. " "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` will show `echo "Feild " . $row["Feild"]. " "<br>";` is a syntax error.

Comment: Also, I guess `SELECT Feild FROM Season 1` is wrong with that space before the 1.

Comment: The issue is that you are not concatenating string properly. Even the StackOverflow syntax highlighter is showing you that there is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have used to display the results was incorrect, replace:

```
echo "Feild " . $row["Feild"]. " "<br>";
```

With:

```
echo 'Feild '.$row["Feild"].'<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not terminated your string properly.

Replace

```
echo "Feild " . $row["Feild"]. " "<br>";
```

With

```
echo "Feild " . $row["Feild"]. "<br>";
```

If you had errors turned on you would be getting an error stating a line number.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know which column you're selecting from, as "*SELECT Feild FROM Season 1*" isn't valid. It should be something like "*SELECT Feild FROM Season WHERE column = '1'*"

With that in mind, this gets you closer to a solution:

```
include 'config.php';

$conn = name2;
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Feild FROM Season 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Feild ". $row["Feild"] ."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correct syntax

```
 echo "Feild ".$row['Feild']."<br>";
```